# send parameter from c# form to php via url

Tags: c#, php, url-rewriting

I want to send a parameter that is asked to the user in a C# form and send it to php page. I also want that php page to open when user clicks a button. I have tried the following:
string fid = textBox1.Text;

```
        ProcessStartInfo p1 = new ProcessStartInfo("https://localhost/filter/abc.php?id=fid");
        Process.Start(p1); 
    }
 echo $_GET['id'];//in php page
```

No variable value is getting passed.I mean on the php page when i print using echo I get fid. Not the value in fid, but the word 'fid' is printed.
I have tried changing the parameter to id=123 and 123 is getting passed. I have also initialized fid to 123 like
      string fid=123;
Again i get 'fid' as output.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are sending the string literal `fid` not the variable contents.  You could do this:

```
ProcessStartInfo p1 = new ProcessStartInfo("https://localhost/filter/abc.php?id=" + fid);
```

Which would use the variable `fid`.  I would have some validation on the Textbox to ensure you don't suffer from `XSS attacks`.